# Python append related records to the concerned person

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Records :

Record 1:
    Name : John
    Phone : 1234567890

Record 2:
    Name : John;
    Phone : 9876543210

Record 3:
    Name : Max;
    Phone : 54565465464

```
Expected Output = Name : John; Phone : 1234567890 , 9876543210.
                  Name : Max; Phone : 54565465464.
```

Comment: I would suggest beginning by defining a structure for your records, and then we can suggest how to modify your structure to come up with expected output

Comment: @Santhosh can you provide any attempts made, any code blocks.... please

Comment: And try to make a reference or relation to Odoo or i will remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
s = [('John', 1234567890), ('John', 9876543210), ('Max', 54565465464)]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)

print(d.items())
```

Reference : https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict